# Kotlin coroutine runTest fails with the delay call

Tags: unit-testing, kotlin-coroutines, coroutinescope

When I have a `delay` call inside a `launch`, the `runTest` in unit tests fails.

```
private val testDispatcher = UnconfinedTestDispatcher()

@Test
fun exampleTest() = runTest(testDispatcher) {
    var result = 0

    val job = launch(testDispatcher) {
        delay(1)
        result = 1
    }

    // advanceUntilIdle()
    println("job.isCompleted: ${job.isCompleted}, result: $result")

    Assert.assertEquals(1, result)
}
```

The output is `job.isCompleted: false, result: 0`.

If I remove the delay or uncomment `advanceUntilIdle()` the test passes, but I cannot get why it is that way.

My thoughts - with that code, I use `testDispatcher` inside the test and inside `launch`, so I expect it to skip delays. Where I am wrong?

Comment: "It should skip the delays" doesn't ensure your coroutine will launch immediately. You still need to call `job.join()` in order to ensure the coroutine you launched has finished

Comment: It will launch and finish immediately if I remove the `delay` call. It will output `job.isCompleted: true` without the job.join due to the `runTest`.

Comment: The docs say delays are skipped, but I don't think that necessarily means it ignores the delay call entirely. It might still be suspending (new continuation) so it behaves like a `yield()` call.